# How to clear cache from library in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, caching, oauth2resttemplate, atlassian-connect

I am pretty new to concept of caching , and i have a situation where i am not using any cache mechanism in my Spring Boot application , but when i open my actuator and go to cache endpoint there is always this

```
"caches": {
        "oauth-2-clients": {
          "target": "com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.UnboundedLocalCache$UnboundedLocalManualCache"
        }
```

and i figured that this cache comes from this library
[AtlassianHostRestClients](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.atlassian.connect/atlassian-connect-spring-boot-api/latest/com/atlassian/connect/spring/AtlassianHostRestClients.html)
and since i use this method from library **authenticatedAsHostActor()**
it will automatically store info about user in cache, but this cause me some errors, and i want to remove this cache from my application
but if i try basic
`@CacheEvict(value="oauth-2-clients", allEntries=true)` it won`t work , and i dont know how to clear it , or how i can disable this cache

I also tried `spring.cache.type=NONE` but it also didn`t help